submit button won't activate on 'enter' key
I have this element
<button type="submit" tabindex="0" autofocus="autofocus" 
        @onclick="StartClick">Start</button>

I want it to trigger on pressing the enter key, but nothing happens.
I've tried wrapping it in a form. No change.
The nav bar on the left has initial focus.
If I put a text box next to it and manually give it focus, the button still doesn't trigger the onclick event.
If I tab to the button, then hit enter, it does trigger.
So I don't think an onkeypress is going to help.
Do I need to give it focus?
Seems like the whole point of 'type=submit' is that it should work regardless of focus.
Trying to do this without resorting to Javascript.

Do you have any sample code of your html structure?

For others, does it matter that this user doesn't have parens on their inline function call?

I guess without more details we can't troubleshoot the issue. Here's a jsfiddle with button working inherently to submit the form. https://jsfiddle.net/pnmk1cfa/

I had a test with code <button @ref="testRef" type="submit" tabindex="0" @onclick="StartClick" @onkeypress="HandleKeyDown">Start</button> which worked for me. But it requires to give focus when page loaded.

trigger on pressing the enter key -> requiring to bind onkeypress event to this button so that it can know we are now trying to mock the button click event. But the onkeypress event requires to focus on the button then it can be triggered. I used @ref="testRef" and await testRef.FocusAsync(); in OnAfterRenderAsync then when I navigate to the target page and press enter, it will trigger the onkeypress event.

there's something else in your page interfering. As per the feature you are expecting, the autofocus attribute alone would be enough as long as that one is the only element having it and there's no other event handlers messing up with that behaviour. I would add that it would be better to have the submit event handler on your parent <EditForm>. You may experiment with html alone before adding noise with blazor so you can better focus the scenario

Enter happens within a form.  Click enter when focus is on any control within the form and the handler assigned to OnSubmit on the form will be triggered.  The button is just a control.  If you want enter to do something anywhere in the form you need to apply the necessary event to a form level div.

Did you add a RenderMode ?

you won't need a handler for type="submit" since its default action will be to fire the <form's submit.  Put your handler in the  tag.  OnSubmit or in the action.
